# Java - Loop Cannot keep track of correct count

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;



public class BlackJack {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Instance of the Scanner 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    playGame();


}

public static void playGame() {
    //int newTotal;
    int total;
    int firstCard;
    int secondCard;
    String readLine;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Instance of the Scanner 
    Random random = new Random(); // Instance of Random
    firstCard = 1 + random.nextInt(10);
    secondCard = 1 + random.nextInt(10);

    System.out.println(firstCard + " , "+ secondCard + " and + 1");
    total = firstCard + secondCard + 1;
    System.out.println("Your total is: " + total);

    System.out.println("Want another card? (y/n)");
    readLine = input.nextLine();
    //           

    int newTotal;

    while (readLine.equals("y")) {
        int finalCard = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println(finalCard);
        newTotal = finalCard + total;
        System.out.println("You new total is: " + newTotal );

        if (newTotal == 21) {
            System.out.println("BlackJack!! You won!");
            break;
        } else if (newTotal > 21) {
            System.out.println("You lose.." );
            break;  
        } else 
            System.out.println("Want another card? (y/n)");
        readLine = input.nextLine();
        newTotal = finalCard + total;

    } 
}
```

}

Currently, I am trying to update the correct amount of newCard total; however, after the second count it goes back to old the value.

For instance,

**

- Console output

**

```
4 , 4 and + 1
Your total is: 9
Want another card? (y/n)
y
8
You new total is: 17
Want another card? (y/n)
y
5
You new total is: 14 // this should be 22 
Want another card? (y/n)
```

The number 3rd output should be 17 + 5; however, my program currently is adding 9 + 5. Please help..

Comment: The code is different of your explanation above

Answer (score 0):

```
newTotal = finalCard + total;
```

Uses the old total (given in the first round) change it to only use the total instead and it should work.

And as suggested before, remove the `newTotal = finalCard + total;` in the else statement

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static void playGame() {
    int total;
    int firstCard;
    int secondCard;
    String readLine;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Instance of the Scanner 
    Random random = new Random(); // Instance of Random
    firstCard = 1 + random.nextInt(10);
    secondCard = 1 + random.nextInt(10);

    System.out.println(firstCard + " , "+ secondCard + " and + 1");
    total = firstCard + secondCard + 1;
    System.out.println("Your total is: " + total);

    System.out.println("Want another card? (y/n)");
    readLine = input.nextLine();


    while (readLine.equals("y")) {
        int finalCard = random.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println(finalCard);
        total += finalCard ;
        System.out.println("You new total is: " + total );

        if (total == 21) {
            System.out.println("BlackJack!! You won!");
            break;
        } else if (total > 21) {
            System.out.println("You lose.." );
            break;  
        } else {
            System.out.println("Want another card? (y/n)");
            readLine = input.nextLine();
        }


    } 
}
```

your new gameloop ;)

Comment: give me a second i'll load it in eclipse

Comment: now it should work :) Notice: I changed the answer 2 times

Comment: newTotal = finalCard +newTotal +total; You do not really need this, just replace it with only using total.

Comment: @asiew did it in the 2nd change

Comment: You still have newTotal = finalCard +newTotal; Just use total instead of declaring a new variable.

Comment: sorry you were right. but know its the complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your while loop should be 
total = finalCard + total;

instead of 
newTotal = finalCard + total;